# Need help with a question

Tags: discussion

I thought this was a good question. [Spinning wing heat dispersion dynamics?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/44600/spinning-wing-heat-dispersion-dynamics) but is down voted. Can someone please help me make this question better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've been trying for literally *years* to improve that question, and every time you do it raises more flags. Most recently due to the fact your edit appears to (perhaps only partly) invalidate existing answers.

I'm not sure there's much salvaging. Its hard to see it as a really good aviation question, it appears partly theoretical (not a good candidate for Q/A), partly physics, and mostly off topic.

In all honesty, you might just be better to let that question die.